# iOS: Creating structured NSArray in given format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

hello all i am working on a project in which i have to create an array in this format:

```
{
            "1": {
                "Child_Gender": "",
                "Child_DOB": "",
                "Child_tobbacoUse": ""
            },
            "2": {
                "Child_Gender": "",
                "Child_DOB": "",
                "Child_tobbacoUse": ""
            },
```

but the array i create gives this format

```
(
        {
        "Child_DOB" = "";
        "Child_Gender" = "";
        "Child_tobbacoUse" = "";
    },
        {
        "Child_DOB" = "";
        "Child_Gender" = "";
        "Child_tobbacoUse" = "";
    }
)
```

i am using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayChildModel.count; i++)
    {
        ChildModel *model = [arrayChildModel objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *keyOrder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Children_Gender[%d]",i];
        NSString *keyQuantity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Children_BirthDate[%d]",i];
        NSString *keyTobacco = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Children_HasTobaccoUsage[%d]",i];

        //NSString *keyNotes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row[%d][description]",i];
        childDateOfBirthStr = model.ChildBirthDate ;
        childGenderStr = model.ChildGender ;
        childTobaccoStr = model.ChildTobaccoUsage;


            NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",keyOrder,childGenderStr];
            NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",keyQuantity,childDateOfBirthStr];
            NSString *string3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",keyTobacco,childTobaccoStr];
            [stringParams appendString:string1];
            [stringParams appendString:string2];
            [stringParams appendString:string3];


            NSDictionary * ChildDict;
            NSArray * ApplicantKeys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Child_Gender",@"Child_DOB",@"Child_tobbacoUse", nil];
            NSArray * ApplicantObjects = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:childGenderStr,childDateOfBirthStr,childTobaccoStr, nil];
            ChildDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:ApplicantObjects forKeys:ApplicantKeys];
            NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@",ChildDict);
            [CompleteArray addObject:ChildDict];

    }
    NSLog(@"Final Array is %@",CompleteArray);
```

please help me to convert the output array to the required formatted array

Comment: its not array its dictionary, try think like dictionary creator.

Answer (score 0):

Create one dictionary outer for loop

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

add this line before   `NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@",ChildDict);`

```
 [dict setObject:ChildDict forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i+1]];
[CompleteArray addObject:dict];
```

Comment: it shows this error [<__NSDictionary0 0x600000013240> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 1.

Comment: NSDictionary is immutable, use NSMutableDictionary instead.

Comment: you need to create NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 0):

Please check following solution it will give you as expected output.

```
     NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayChildModel.count; i++)
    {


            ChildModel *model = [arrayChildModel objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *keyOrder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Children_Gender[%d]",i];
            NSString *keyQuantity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Children_BirthDate[%d]",i];
            NSString *keyTobacco = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Children_HasTobaccoUsage[%d]",i];

            //NSString *keyNotes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row[%d][description]",i];
            childDateOfBirthStr = model.ChildBirthDate ;
            childGenderStr = model.ChildGender ;
            childTobaccoStr = model.ChildTobaccoUsage;


            NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",keyOrder,childGenderStr];
            NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",keyQuantity,childDateOfBirthStr];
            NSString *string3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",keyTobacco,childTobaccoStr];
            [stringParams appendString:string1];
            [stringParams appendString:string2];
            [stringParams appendString:string3];


            NSDictionary * ChildDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:childGenderStr,@"Child_Gender",childDateOfBirthStr,@"Child_DOB",childTobaccoStr,@"Child_tobbacoUse", nil];
            NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@",ChildDict);

            NSString *resultDicKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1];
            [resultDic setValue:ChildDict forKey:resultDicKey];

    }

    NSLog(@"Result dic %@",resultDic);
```